# How to load aidl files to Android Studio

Tags: android, aidl

I want to use xuxingliu922/barcodescan (https://github.com/xuxingliu922/barcodescan/wiki/Instructions-for-use ) for my project. It is an aidl . It has a kullanım user guide. But I followed all instruction. I can not do that. I want to only print a few values from post writer.  I did create an aidl folder. then I clicked finish button. Then; I see nothing. But instructions were saying "the application module will appear with a manifest, java, and res at the same level of the folder aidl"
How can I load this aidl. You can see my screen below image.I google it and read me text folder.

another link in read me text folder:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjNKm.png)

I did it like said you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mC0FM.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to aidl file in `src/main/aidl/` and the subfolder it belongs too

For example : IInAppBillingService.aidl would be in the package `com.android.vending.billing` under `src/main/aidl/`